# Feature Request for Swift Perfect - RAML

Tags: swift, perfect

As per http://perfect.org/feature-requests.html

I would like to request that [RAML](http://raml.org) functionality be included out of the box.

I would like to see something like the following on the server for serving RAML documentation:

```
server.addRamlDocs(path: "/raml.raml", versionRaml: 1.0, versionApi: "v1", title: "Test API title")
```

This would add a route that when matched creates a full RAML file for all RAML routes.

RAML routes should probably be created in a similar fashion to MustachePageHandler but split into RamlDescriptionHandler, RamlValidateRequestHandler, RamlRequestHandler and RamlResponseHandler.

**RamlDescriptionHandler**

This should be responsible for:

- Describing the request / response
- Automatically creating documentation for the request (when server docs matched)

**RamlValidateRequestHandler**

- Validating and type casting the request

This should then inject HTTPRequest.ramlRequestData and HTTPRequest.ramlRequestIsValid.  This should require no action from the application developer.

**RamlRequestHandler**

Application logic to be coded by the developer, should check and use HTTPRequest.ramlRequestData and HTTPRequest.ramlRequestIsValid

Should set HTTPResponse.ramlStatus (HTTP Status Code) and HTTPResponse.ramlData

**RamlResponseHandler**

Should validate the response and send matching against RamlDescriptionHandler, no action from the application developer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question, it is a feature request for a specific piece of software.

Comment: @joseph-earl The Swift Perfect documentation asks for feature requests to be raised here in the format provided.  Please see http://perfect.org/feature-requests.html as per the first line of my post.  Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for programming questions, not product feature requests. Feature requests are clearly stated as improper use of this site on http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support. The Perfect developers should use another service such as uservoice.com for this.

Comment: I've started a project for this on [github](https://github.com/openbuild-sheffield/jolt)

Will happily accept feedback, contributors, pull requests etc